# Closing reasons for identify-this-game questions

Tags: discussion, closing, game-identification

I'm puzzled about why [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27052/an-adventure-game-with-a-rhino-like-pet-closed) question has been closed.

IMEO, identify-this-game questions should be closed if they have so few details they can "match" multiple games; while I agree that the linked question is vague at best, it contains some elements that are very unlikely present in other games. This means that if someone who *has* actually played that game notices the question, he *can* answer, and the answer will be correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I agree that this question is probably answerable, as is, by someone who remembers that game well.** On the other hand, I feel that sometimes we just have to draw the line when a question is too vague, among other reasons because **the more vague it is, the less likely it is to ever be useful for anyone else.**

In this particular question, the fact the OP hasn't supplied a year, or even a decade, is already alarming. And he "thinks" it was a pet Rhino. And he remembers one very short puzzle (?). He provided no information about gameplay or perspective, which I consider important. And his comment about the art style is very vague.

Comment: Fine, I agree, but only because - as you pointed out - there are *some* details that he **certainly** could have provided (decade, etc.) and he didn't.

Answer (score 9):

There's two distinct possible bad avenues that an "identify-this-game" can go. The one you're noting is when *the details match way too many games*, then it is difficult to narrow down the target.

The other possible avenue is when *the details don't match any game*. This is the hardest criteria to judge on, of course, being that it's on the same lines as proving a negative. But this was, as it were, the biggest issue with identification questions and the one thing that Jeff Atwood especially didn't like about them - these are susceptible to whatever whims and distortion that memory provides. What even sticks as a very distinct detail may even be completely false.

I'll recant a memory I had of doing an identification question on an IRC channel years ago. I wanted to recall an SNES platformer I had played in my youth, which I recalled two distinct elements. You had a selection of tools you could switch through at the top of the screen, one of which was something like an exploding lollipop. As well, the character herself was a some sort of cute valkyrie girl, and one the first stages was shining castle.

Someone *did* know what I was talking about. The game ended up being [Magical Pop'n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_Pop%27n), which stars a little blond magician girl veritably wearing a blue version of Link's outfit, and the stage I had thought was a brilliantly colored fortress was actually... a city and its sewers. Memory does that, y'know.

Or if we want a more local example, take [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18493/racing-pc-game-like-mario-kart). The key identifying point to distinguish itself from other animal racing games is the firing of monkeys. *Except they weren't monkeys, they were hedgehogs*. There are a lot of other identifying factors one might've provided (the moose's name was Morris, matches were one of the best weapons, etc.), but the combination of a whole lot of details and date got the game a lot easier than if it had just been a scant few.

Until the actual game is revealed, it is difficult to assess what details are fact, and which are whimsy. That's why having a lot of different details such as date, platform, style, and everything else is important - no matter how specific or unique a single piece of detail is, if it's completely wrong or otherwise inaccurate, then it's just leading everyone on a wild goose chase. Sometimes, there just isn't enough information provided in a question, whether it is to distinguish itself from other games, or simply to be identified for what it is.

Comment: god, how I hate this class of questions. I know hate is a strong word.. but *hate*.

Comment: @Jeff As of late... I feel as if I am starting to know how you feel.

Comment: I could have sworn we discussed removing these questions from the site rather recently.  Whatever came of that?